# Don't use System.Threading.Timer to synchronize?

Tags: .net, timer, locking

I have some code looking like this:

```
using System.Threading;

public sealed class MyClass : IDisposable {
    private readonly Timer _timer;

   public MyClass() {
        _timer = new Timer(MyCallback);
   }

   public void SomeMethod() {
       lock (_timer) {
           ...
       }
   }

   ...
```

}

When I run code analysis (FxCop) I get the error message
`CA2002 : Microsoft.Reliability : 'MyClass.SomeMethod' locks on a reference of type 'Timer'. Replace this with a lock against an object with strong-identity.`

[I found some documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182290.aspx).

> An object is said to have a weak identity when it can be directly accessed across application domain boundaries.

How can my private timer object be accessed across appdomains? The only reason I can think of is if the Timer class wraps some global system handle but I don't understand how that handle is involved in the locking.

There is a list of weak classes on the documentation page but Timer is not mentioned. MemomoryStream is also not on the list but it is included in the examples. How can a local MemoryStream object be weak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Timer` extends [`MarshalByRefObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx), which is why it's complaining, I suspect.

Personally I would recommend only locking on a private object which *only* your code can know about:

```
using System.Threading;

public sealed class MyClass : IDisposable {
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private readonly object _mutex = new object();

   public MyClass() {
        _timer = new Timer(MyCallback);
   }

   public void SomeMethod() {
       lock (_mutex) {
           ...
       }
   }

   ...
}
```

That way you don't need to worry about whether `Timer` decides to lock on `this` etc.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to get around it but don't understand why just some classes are listed if a potential lock on a public object is the problem.

Comment: @adrianm: Well, a potential lock on a public object is *a* problem in general; but locking on a `MarshalByRefObject` allows code running in one AppDomain to lock on an object in another AppDomain, so it's even more potentially problematic.

Comment: Do you mean that my private MarshalByRefObject might make itself visible to other appdomains? Otherwise I don't understand how anyone else can use it in a lock.

Comment: @adrianm: I'm saying that it's *possible* to share `MarshalByRefObjects` objects across AppDomains, unlike most objects (which are copied when they're marshalled). I'm not saying it would happen with your code - but it's a risk which FxCop is highlighting.

Comment: Still don't understand why a private MarshalByRefObject is worse than a private object, except the appdomain part, but I'll mark this as an answer. I think it is easier to get the lock right if I lock on the same object as the lock is protecting

Comment: @adrianm: The point is that if you've got any other kind of object, then the object itself may lock on it. I trust that no code in `System.Object` has a `lock(this)` statement - I don't trust anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You can't be sure that `Timer` doesn't lock itself on its instance. Its best to use just a `new object()`.